# Can I use rvalue to store the intermediate results

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I found it slow when calculate expression of array. So I wonder
about can I use rvalue to store the intermediate results for reducing alloc action?

```
#include "SArray.hpp"

template <typename T>
SArray<T>&& operator* (SArray<T>&& s, const T& scale) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
        s[i] *= scale;
    return std::move(s);
}

int main() {

    SArray<int> w = SArray<int>({1,2,3,4,5,6}) * 2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. You can. Topic close :P

Comment: BTW, you should write `return s;`.. that is better than `return std::move(s);` The former facilitates copy/move-elision by the compiler.

Comment: Also, if `SArray` stores the data as part of the object (rather than holding a pointer or something), then moves will likely be as slow as copies.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0040__Data-Types/SArray.htm) your `SArray`?

Comment: @Nawaz `std::move` is a no-op in this case. The function returns a reference (to the same object that `s` refers to) - there is no copy or move to elide.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: ahh.. yes. I didn't notice that ...(But then I guess that is *not* what  OP intended).

Comment: @Yakk Yep I come this idea when learning ETs

Comment: Dont think that SArray class implements move, you should add move assignment operator to the class.